# Q - How To Use SalesForce Offline On A Laptop/PC?

Tags: salesforce1-app, offline

I have tried using the Salesforce [Offline Edition](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=briefcase_with_connect_offline.htm&type=5) as a way of accessing and adjusting the data offline. But after doing plenty of research and testing I concluded that the benefits are heavily outnumbered by disbenefits. To even use the SalesForce Offline Edition effectively I need to be using windows 7 operating system and an outdated version of Internet Explorer.

I also used the Salesforce Mobile App which is great and does do the job, but it isn't available on Windows devices.

[Pulsar](https://luminixinc.com/pricing/) is another option I found that is absolutely amazing but we have so many different users that its just not cost effective at all.

So basically what is the best and most optimal way of accessing Salesforce offline?

Can I make an App accessible offline?
Or Can I make a VisualForce Page accessible offline with the fields I want to capture?

Thanks for any information

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **could** cast phone on laptop but I guess you wanted "desktop-like" capabilities? I am sure there are plenty of reasons for offline mode application but there is no standard, easy way of doing that today - unfortunately. The difficult way if you ask will be to build a custom application and sync that with SFDC.
There is an idea sticking around about enabling offline mode for quite some time - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Z9BwAAK. I am not sure whether it will go anywhere soon in the always-connected world that we live in.